# How to avoid unintended Hash-Key manipulation

Tags: java, hash

I noticed that adding an element to a list does change its hash-key value and therefore it cannot be accessed again since `.contains(modifiedObject)` won't get a collision here. I did not expect that behavior to be honest. Makes me wonder how `HashSet` does its hashing .. So how can I make sure to *not* destroy my `HashSet` as I modify e.g. a list of strings as shown below. Is there a method to do that safe or is that just something I have to look out as a programmer?

```
private HashSet<List<String>> bagOfWordsMap = new HashSet<List<String>>();

private void createBagOfWordsList(UnifiedTag[] invalidTags) {


    for(List<String> sentences : getSentenceList()) {

        List<String> sentenceStemWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Not what you would want to do since sentenceStemWords is 
        // modified right after and bagOfWordsMap.contains(sentenceStemWords)
        // won't collide again:

        // bagOfWordsMap.add(sentenceStemWords);

        for(String word : sentences) {

            String stem = Stemmer.getStem(word);
            sentenceStemWords.add(stem);
        }   

        bagOfWordsMap.add(sentenceStemWords);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in some subclass of `ArrayList` that you've made?

Comment: @christopher: what would be a useful/meaningful alternative definition of `equals`?

Comment: Perhaps collating the values *inside* the list into some format?

Comment: In `C` I might think of just hashing the objects start address in memory I don't know if that is smart but I guess that would be one way to ensure that you always get back the *object* you wanted to get access to later on. I am not sure if or how I could do such a thing in Java but overriding `hashCode` seems to be a possible solution for that.

Comment: I have the feeling that the problem is that a `Set` is not the correct data structure for what you want. Why a `Set` and not something else? How do you get the lists from the Set?

Comment: @Augusto I am comparing lists A and B with objects and look for similarities. As soon as I got two elements which are similar I want to remove that from B in order to decrease the amount of comparisons if possible. I am using `Set` to be able to delete in O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Never use a mutable object as key in a map or set

Implement a frozen type that cannot be modified *anymore* if you want to prevent accidential modification!

- fine print: it's technically okay to have mutable attributes on an object if they don't change the key, but you won't be able to access them easily by key in a java set, as there is no `HashSet.get` to get the current member, only a `contains`. Also, it's bad style and fragile. It's much better to split such objects into key, value.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use an `UnmodifiableList<String>` instead of a `List<String>` in your `HashSet`.

Another option is to use a `HashMap<String,List<String>>` instead of your `HashSet<List<String>>`, provided that you can associate some unique `String` key with each of your `List`s.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure OP won't be able to add it into the list in the first place?

Comment: @christopher It would force him to remove a List from the HashSet and add a new List with the modified content. While this would have some performance cost, it would protect against corrupting the HashSet.

Comment: Aaaah yes. Sorry, it's early! +1.

Comment: Okay I guess that is also a valid solution but only in the case if I a) want to disallow manipulation of my `List<String>` and b) have to live with the fact that I am only allowed to add the object to the hash map *after* initializing it.

Comment: @StefanFalk what HashMap? Your code uses a HashSet. If you keep the lists as the values in a HashMap (and decide on some unique immutable key), you'll be able to modify them after adding them to the Map.

Comment: @Eran Sorry I did mean HashSet :) I am aware of the possibility to use a `HashMap` but I dislike that option since I'd have to think about how to generate such a key and make it accessible when I need it.

Comment: Another problem is that `UnmodifiableList<String>` only returns a view of that object but the underlying object is still modifiable since `.get(key)` returns the `List<String>` object as is.